# How to show data from a database in netbeans Consol

Tags: java, jdbc

I want to display my record in the consol of netbeans. I have two Column: "naam" and "AantalTespelenRondes". I want to display them + the records of the database.
Here is my code of connecting to the database through code.

I work with a List where it saves the data of the database. But when I exucute I get this

```
[domein.Spel@bddc6, domein.Spel@b0cf230]
```

And that are not the records. How can I show the records + column names in the consol of netbeans

```
private final static String LEES_SPELERS_SQL = "SELECT Naam, AantalTeSpelenRondes FROM Spel";

  public List<Spel> geefSpel()
{
    List<Spel> spelLijst = new ArrayList<Spel>();
    //create Statement for querying database
    Statement statement;
    Connection connection = PersistentieController.getInstance().getConnection();
    try
    {
        statement = connection.createStatement();

        // query database
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(LEES_SPELERS_SQL);

        while (resultSet.next())
        {

            String Naam = resultSet.getString("Naam");
            int AantalRondes = resultSet.getInt("AantalTeSpelenRondes");


               Spel spel = new Spel(Naam,AantalRondes);
               spelLijst.add(spel);


        }
        statement.close();
       // return Spel;
    } catch (SQLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return spelLijst;
```

Comment: Did you override `toString` method in `Spel` class?

Comment: No, I don't have any errors etc, Maybe I need to use something else then a list for the records?

Comment: I never said if you had errors. I asked you if you override `toString` method in `Spel` class...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I work with a List where it saves the data of the database. But when I exucute I get this
>
> ```
> [domein.Spel@bddc6, domein.Spel@b0cf230]
> ```

You're currently printing the `Spel` object reference and it will use `toString` method. Since you haven't overridden it, it will use [`Object#toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--).

You have two approaches to solve this *problem*:

- Override `toString` method in `Spel` class:

  ```
  @Override
  public String toString() {
      //assuming this class has Naam and aantalRondes fields
      //replace by the real fields in your class
      return "{ Naam: " + naam + ", AantalRondes: " + aantalRondes + "}";
  }
  ```
- Go through every element in the `List` and manually print the desired data:

  ```
  for (Spel spel : spelLijst) {
      //use the format you want/need
      System.out.println(spel.getNaam() + " " + spel.getAantalRondes());
  }
  ```

Comment: Ok thx, I uses the Override method and it works ! thank you very much